# How to optimize this query - replace/optimize NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query should return values that are not included in the top - for example - 10.
Anyway to optimize it? Maybe replace NOT IN?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procName 
    @ClientId char(36)
    , @Top int
    , @StartDate datetime
    , @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        'Outside' AS LocationName
        , SUM(Copies * Pages) AS TotalPages
    FROM table1 tb1 
    INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.Tb2Id = tb1.Tb2Id 
    INNER JOIN [table3] tb3 ON tb3.LocationId = tb2.LocationId
    WHERE tb1.ClientId = @ClientId AND tb1.TimeOrdered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
        AND tb3.[Name] NOT IN (
            SELECT TOP(@Top)
                tb3.[Name] AS LocationName
            FROM table1 tb1 
            INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.Tb2Id = tb1.Tb2Id 
            INNER JOIN [table3] a ON tb3.LocationId = tb2.LocationId
            WHERE tb1.ClientId = @ClientId AND tb1.TimeOrdered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
            GROUP BY tb3.Name
            ORDER BY SUM(tb1.Copies * tb1.Pages) DESC   
        )
END
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: Query Plan and DDL of the tables and respective indexes will also greatly help for performance questions.

Comment: So little effort put in, -1

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT
    'Outside' AS LocationName
    , SUM(Copies * Pages) AS TotalPages
FROM table1 tb1 
INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.Tb2Id = tb1.Tb2Id 
INNER JOIN [table3] tb3 ON tb3.LocationId = tb2.LocationId
left outer join 
(
            SELECT TOP(@Top)
                tb3.[Name] AS LocationName
            FROM table1 tb1 
            INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.Tb2Id = tb1.Tb2Id 
            INNER JOIN [table3] a ON tb3.LocationId = tb2.LocationId
            WHERE tb1.ClientId = @ClientId AND tb1.TimeOrdered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
            GROUP BY tb3.Name
            ORDER BY SUM(tb1.Copies * tb1.Pages) DESC  
) z on z.LocationName = tb3.LocationName
WHERE tb1.ClientId = @ClientId AND tb1.TimeOrdered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
and z.LocationName is null
```

This gets rid of the NOT IN, but doesn't remove the select TOP, which it looks like you need anyway.

Without knowing the indexes available, and probably row counts in the tables involved, there's not a lot more anyone can tell you as the comments on the question note.